# Beautifulsoup/Selenium how to scrape website until next page is disabled?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

So I have a list of urls (called "data") that contains urls like
https://www.amazon.com/Airpods-Fashion-Protective-Accessories-Silicone/product-reviews/B08YD8JLNQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews

and

https://www.amazon.com/Keychain-R-fun-Protective-Accessories-Visible-Sky/product-reviews/B082W7DL1R/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews

Some urls do not have the "Next Page" icon  and some do. So far my code is something like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException


df = pd.read_csv(r'path to csv file', sep=',', usecols=['Url'], squeeze=True)
data = pd.read_csv(r'path to csv file', sep=',', usecols=['Url'], squeeze=True)
rows = []

for url in data
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup.prettify
    
    #names = soup.find_all('span', class="a-profile-name")
    # div.celwidget div.aok-relative span.a-profile-name
    #names = soup.find_all('div.celwidget div.aok-relative span', class= "a-profile-name")
    names = soup.find_all('div.celwidget div.aok-relative span.a-profile-name')
    rating = soup.find_all('div.celwidget div.aok-relative span.a-icon-alt')
    title = soup.find_all('div.celwidget div.aok-relative a.a-text-bold span')
    content = soup.find_all('div.celwidget div.aok-relative span.review-text-content span')
```

I want to scrape the names, ratings and etc from the reviews until the last item where the Next Page button would be disabled.
I'm not quite sure what to do from here, I looked around and many questions related to this was using .click() on Next Page which I don't think is the answer I need/want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next page url is stored in a list item with class name `a-last`. So you could create a `while` loop that breaks if `soup.find('li', class_='a-last')` returns nothing anymore (i.e. if the last page has been reached):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

url='https://www.amazon.com/Keychain-R-fun-Protective-Accessories-Visible-Sky/product-reviews/B082W7DL1R/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews' #or https://www.amazon.com/s?k=maison+kitsune+airpod+pro+case
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

while True:
  wd.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, "html.parser")
  #store data here

  try:
    url = 'https://www.amazon.com/' + soup.find('li', class_='a-last').find('a', href=True)['href']
    time.sleep(2) #prevent ban
  except:
    break
```

Comment: any reason why you would store data from first page outside the loop instead of some way to store data from all pages inside the loop?

Comment: That was just a remnant of wanting to use a for loop. You're right, it can be run in the while loop, I've updated the answer.

Comment: I had TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable for the line: url = 'https://www.amazon.com/' + soup.find('li', class_='a-last').find('a', href=True)['href']

Comment: Seems to to do everything fine but I get that error when it hits the last page of the item

Comment: I also tried it with a new url that has fewer reviews but getting same error? url: https://www.amazon.com/Arti-Cipes-Electric-Cosmetic-Automatic-Machine-Spinner/product-reviews/B08QMKN8Z8/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews

Comment: Ok I have changed the if-else to try-except. That should fix it.